# What is Selectivity?

Tags: sql-server

The problem is I don't understand--no I DO understand selectivity--but I keep reading different definitions of it, which is confusing.

What I think (based on [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/index-selectivity-and-index-scans) by Gail Shaw): Selectivity is what predicates have. Columns aren't selective. Indexes aren't selective. Operators aren't selective. **Selectivity is a measure of the percentage of rows that the predicate affects.**

The confusion:

*SQL Server Execution plans 3rd edition, Grant Fritchey*. Page 223. He says

> The selectivity of a predicate, for a given index, is the expected ratio of matching rows. Count the total number of rows in the table (z), count the number of distinct values (x) for a given column, or combination of columns, across all the rows, and then (x/z) gives the selectivity of the index, for an equality predicate comparing the column (or columns) against unknown values.

> A highly selective index will have a low selectivity value. For example, a selectivity of
> 0.01 (1%) means that the optimizer expects 1% of the total rows in the table to match the predicate. Conversely, the worst possible selectivity is 1.0 (or 100%) meaning that every row will match the predicate condition.

Eh? I thought highly selective, i.e. 100%, i.e. 100% of the values are distinct, was a GOOD thing.
But he says 100% is the worst possible selectivity.

Then in [this](https://www.programmerinterview.com/database-sql/selectivity-in-sql-databases/) article, they calculate the selectivity of a column with 2 distinct values (gender) to be 0.02%. But 0.02% isn't good surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're a little stuck on the semantics, but both definitions are saying the same thing, just in slightly different ways. Think of **selectivity** meaning **how selective** the values are in a given dataset. The more selective a value is, the more frequently occuring that value is in the dataset. Like a bowl of fruit that has 4 oranges and 1 apple - if you stuck your hand in the bowl randomly your odds of pulling out an orange is much higher than an apple, so the oranges are more selective.

If for example, you had a column in your table where **every** row had the same exact value, that value is highly selective, actually, the highest of selectivity, because if you were to select rows based on that value you'd get every row back. This is 100% selectivity.

The reason why high selectivity is not necessarily a good thing is because as a predicate it doesn't reduce the dataset before the data is returned, so it's essentially not very useful to filter on. The selectivity of the values in your predicates help determine what operators the SQL Server Engine will use to serve the data efficiently. Values that are low selectivity can elicit a [**seek** operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40486614/5059085) which is typically more efficient by directly seeking out **only** the data pages of the rows needed to serve the query. Values that are highly selective require a **scan** operation which essentially scans through **all** of the data pages of the table (so the entire table itself) to locate the rows required for the query.

The case where high selectivity *can be good* is when you want to use a **columnstore** index which compresses the data down the column within the index (as opposed to a rowstore which indexes across the row). This is great especially on columns where you want to quickly aggregate, such as a `QuantitySold` field in a `SalesOrderDetails` table grouped by `ItemType`, to find the total of each good sold, for example. The reason high selectivity is good here is because the higher the selectivity, the higher the compression ratio you'll get from the column being compressed.

Comment: So high selectivity can be a good thing or a bad thing. It just depends on what you mean by highly selective.

Comment: @jupiter It depends, and when I get a chance I'll update my answer with this because you reminded me of something. So in a typical rowstore (standard B-Tree index), it's good when your predicates have low selectivity, because that means the data is being filtered well, and less data will need to be returned, thus hopefully eliciting a **seek** operation to find the data - which is very performant. E.g. if your table has 1 billion rows in it, but your predicate is on a value that exists only 10 times, that'll be very fast for SQL Server to locate the data because of the low selectivity which...

Comment: ...should result in an index seek operation. Even if the table grew to 1 trillion records, it still would be very quick for 10 rows to be located. In the case where high selectivity can be good is when you want to use a columnstore index which compresses the data down the column within the index. This is great especially on columns where you want to quickly aggregate, such as a `QuantitySold` field in a `SalesOrderDetails` table grouped by `ItemType`, for example.

Answer (score 10):

Selectivity is the property of a query predicate. One way to [define selectivity is this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=concepts-selectivity-predicates):

> *Selectivity* refers to the probability that any row will satisfy a predicate (that is, be true).

Thus

> a selectivity of 0.01 (1%) for a predicate operating on a table with 1,000,000 rows means that the predicate returns an estimated 10,000 rows (1% of 1,000,000), and discards an estimated 990,000 rows.

High probability of a row to match the predicate means high value of selectivity.

Unfortunately, the choice of words is confusing, as you have found out:

> A highly selective predicate (one with a selectivity of 0.10 or less) is desirable.

A "highly selective" ("very selective" might have been a better choice) predicate leads to a low selectivity value (i.e. low probability of a given row to match the predicate).

---

It appears that many people, including the authors of sources you quote, use the term "selectivity" to mean something entirely different. They often call it "index selectivity" and calculate it as the ratio of the index key cardinality (the number of distinct key values) to the underlying relation cardinality. Thus, the more distinct key values there are, the higher (closer to 1) the "selectivity", which is of course the inverse of the predicate selectivity for that combination of columns.

The confusion seems to be perpetrated by the [SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-ver15#density), where it states (emphasis mine):

> Density is information about the number of duplicates in a given column or combination of columns and it is calculated as 1/(number of distinct values). The Query Optimizer uses densities to enhance cardinality estimates for queries that return multiple columns from the same table or indexed view. **As density decreases, selectivity of a value increases.**

Taking into account that

> Frequency is information about the occurrence of each distinct value in the first key column of the statistics object, and is calculated as row count * density. A maximum frequency of 1 can be found in columns with unique values.

we can see that value frequency = row count / (number of distinct values) and realize that the inverse of that Microsoft calls "value selectivity". Subsequently, the lower the number of distinct values, the higher the value frequency and the lower the value selectivity. This seems to be what your sources are talking about (though confusingly the first source mentions the predicate selectivity in the same sentence).

All that being said, when you are reading about "selectivity" you need to understand what *kind* of selectivity the particular author has in mind.